# How to remove/hide 'Property Pages' button from a PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I'm working on a propertyGrid panel and I'm trying to remove or hide Property Pages button as it is useless to me, I tried setting ToolBarVisible to false but that hides all the three buttons in the toolbar. Here is what my property grid looks like:

[image]

Comment: `ToolbarVisible` hides that *and the other two*; is that sufficient?

Comment: @MarcGravell I do need the other two to sort the properties by category or alphabetically.

Comment: k, in that case: I'm not aware of a simple way to do that, sorry; maybe somebody else does...

Comment: There's nothing documented. But you can hack it, for example: `var bs = propertyGrid1.Controls.OfType<ToolStrip>().FirstOrDefault().Items; bs[bs.Count - 1].Visible = false; bs[bs.Count - 2].Visible = false;` for reference this is the code that creates it (seems it's always at the end): https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGrid.cs,4496

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: @SimonMourier that worked smoothly! Thanks you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no official way, but you can hack the property grid, accessing it's internal controls.

Here is a sample code that tries to do it the most gracefully possible. You could also test if the last control's text is "Property Pages", but it may not work with localized versions.

```
var buttons = propertyGrid1.Controls.OfType<ToolStrip>().FirstOrDefault()?.Items;
if (buttons != null &&
    buttons.Count >= 2 &&
    buttons[buttons.Count - 1] is ToolStripButton && // could test Text...
    buttons[buttons.Count - 2] is ToolStripSeparator)
{
    buttons[buttons.Count - 1].Visible = false;
    buttons[buttons.Count - 2].Visible = false;
}
```

Use at your own risks.